# Spark: Add Regex column into Row

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I am writing a spark job which iterates through dataset and finds matches, here's what the pseudo code looks like:

```
def map(data: Dataset[Row], queries: Array[Row]): Dataset[Row] = {
    import spark.implicits._
    val val1 = data
      .flatMap(r => {
        val text = r.getAs[String]("text");
        queries.filter(t => t.getAs[String]("query").r.findFirstIn(message).text)
          .map(..//mapping)
      }).toDF(..columns);
}
```

So, it iterates through the data and performs regex matching. The issue is, it tries to convert string into regex (`t.getAs[String]("query").r`) every time, and I am trying to swap it outside the loop as it's not really needed.

So, I tried this (where queries array is generated):

```
val convertToRegex = udf[Regex, String]((arg:String) => if(arg != null) arg.r else null)
queries.withColumn("queryR", convertToRegex(col("query"))) //queries is DataFrame here
```

However, as expected, it threw an error saying (`Schema for type scala.util.matching.Regex is not supported`).

Is there any way I can add a `Regex` column into an `array` or create a `temp` column before stating the iteration?